# Is there a way to listen for the completion of a MovieClip playing?

Tags: actionscript-3, listener, addeventlistener, playback

I want to execute a function upon completion of a MovieClip's animation.  That is, I would command it to play() or gotoAndPlay().  I don't know of any listener that I can attach to the MovieClip with the "addEventListener()" command.  Have any idea I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the addFrameScript method, as shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099049/stopping-on-the-last-frame-flash/2106190#2106190) to dispatch a custom event when the last frame is reached.

Comment: nice hack. More elegant than my answer.

Comment: Awesome.  I wonder why the 'addFrameScript' method isn't documented in the as3 reference?

Comment: I don't think it is recommended by Adobe, but apparently it's what they use internally. But there is nowhere saying NOT to use it! Often languages have undocumented APIs ie Apple's iPhone framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onCheckAnimationComplete)

function onCheckAnimationComplete(e:Event)
{
    if(animation.currentFrame==animation.totalFrames)
    {
        //TODO call a function
    }
}
```