# Event.ENTER_FRAME is executed before the frame is rendered

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there a way to check if the entered frame is already rendered instead of using Timers in

the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` function handler?

I don't like the idea of using Timer because my code is executed before the frame is

completely loaded.

Here is an example:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameEnterEventHandler);
gotoAndPlay("Frame2");

private function frameEnterEventHandler(e:Event):void
{
    myMovieClip.visible = false;
}
```

This code throws an error "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."
Because myMovieClip which is Movie Clip object in Frame 2 is not rendered yet.

so i have to do the following

```
private function frameEnterEventHandler(e:Event):void
{
    setTimeout(blaBla, 100);
}

private function blaBla():void
{ 
    myMovieClip.visible = false;
}
```

what I would like to do if its possible

```
private function frameRenderCompleteEventHandler(e:Event):void
{
  myMovieClip.visible = false;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Note that setTimeOut will cause a memory leak unless you use clearTimeout()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get around your problem, just do this:

```
private function frameEnterEventHandler(e:Event):void
{
    if (myMovieClip) myMovieClip.visible = false;
}
```

Your ENTER_FRAME handler will still be called on each frame, but the clip will only be set to invisible if it actually exists. And of course, you can use the same trick for a timer or delayed method call.

However, you should either a) not use ENTER_FRAME for this kind of functionality or b) remove the event handler immediately after the MovieClip was set to invisible, because otherwise your method will be called over and over on each frame, even though it has long served its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at undocumented method `addFrameScript` :

http://www.ryac.ca/blog/2008/05/the-undocumented-addframescript-method/

(from this so question : [stopping on the last frame (flash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099049/stopping-on-the-last-frame-flash/2106190#2106190))

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the version of the Flash player. In Flash 9, the frame would render before enter frame. In Flash 10+, the frame renders after.

Check out this blog post for information on techniques that will allow you to determine that your objects have arrived on stage without the expense of an enter frame event listener: http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html