# Detect Current Frame within labeled Timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I need to make an Animation called Swing, where it will be only done once when Player hit spacebar or something. my player have labeled timeline where each label is called from AC3 and Swap current label with new one, the problem i am facing is I need to use mc just once, and once its finished it go back to Idle label. I tried to check currentframe but it was '1' and not increasing, also used all solutions here :

[stopping on the last frame (flash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099049/stopping-on-the-last-frame-flash)

with no luck at all. as I am not dealing with an actual mc, I am dealing with a frame and inside the frame is a mc.

more illustration :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GENnl.png

Any ideas ?

Comment: currentFrame refers to the frame-number of the MC you place this code in, not the frame-number of the actual MC with the animation. try player.currentFrame (or whatever object does the animation)

Comment: Will not work as I mentioned, see this : http://gyazo.com/0d4d39a37905eb961c78f190f643869a.png

If I did player.currentFrame I will get a 5.

if I did totoswing, I will get an undefined Object error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as I see from your images you actually need to check the frame of `player.totoswing.currentFrame`, but before you do this make sure the `totoswing` MovieClip exists inside player. It may not exist if `currentFrame` of the player is not 5.

So to check the current frame of your animation you do this:

```
if(player.totoswing)
    trace(player.totoswing.currentFrame);
```

If you want to stop it at the last frame you can add a `stop()` scirpt on the last frame of your totoswing MovieClip.

If you want to know when the totoswing animation goes to the end you can do the following:

```
if(player.totoswing)
{
    player.totoswing.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onTotoSwingFrame);
    player.totoswing.play();
}

function onTotoSwingFrame(e:Event):void
{
    if(e.target.currentFrame == e.target.totalFrames)
    {
        //animation has ended
        e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onToToSwingFrame);
        // do whatever you want. ex. play the idle state
    }
}
```

We first add a listener to the `ENTER_FRAME` event of the `player.totoswing` MovieClip, so that it fires an event everytime it advances a frame. In the event handler (`onTotoSwingFrame`) we check if `player.totoswing` current frame is equal to its total frames and if it is we stop the playback and we know that the animation has finished. We don't need an `ENTER_FRAME` listener anymore so we remove it.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know that its possible that I can add "player.totoswing" before currentFrame, now everything is Good for me :)

Comment: Great! you can access nested `DisplayObjects` and any properties using the dot(.) operator.